# How to use nested routes to add content to a page without removing the content of the previous route with react-router-v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm using the sidebar example provided in the official documentation of react-router-v4 as an inspiration https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar

1- So the initial URL of my application would be : `localhost:3000/search-page/Lists`

2- I have a list of clickable Links that when clicked display the clicked data on the sidebar, and when this happens the URL gets updated :  `localhost:3000/search-page/Lists/itemList1selected`

3- I then press on the button "Show List number 2" to display a new list

4- my goal is using nested routes, when I click on a Link from "List number 2". it would append it below the item selected from "List number 1" ... and update the URL at the same time : `localhost:3000/search-page/Lists/itemList1selected/itemList2selected`

here's my current code :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
     this.state = {
      showListButtonPressed: true
     };
   this.showTheOtherList = this.ShowTheOtherList.bind(this);
  }

  showTheOtherList() {
   this.setState({
     showListButtonPressed: !this.state.showListButtonPressed
   });
  }

 render() {
   const dataList1 = dataFromDataBase
     .allItemsFromList1()
     .map(list1 => ({
       path: `${this.props.match.params.type}/${list1.id}`,
       mainList1: () => (
        <div>
          {`${list1.company}   ${list1.name}   ${list1.price}`}
        </div>
       ),
       sidebarList1: () => (
         <div>
           <h3>item List 1 selected</h3>
             {list1.company}
         </div>
       )
     }));

   const dataList2 = fakeFlightApiDataTesting
     .allItemsFromList2()
     .map(list2 => ({
       path: `${this.props.match.params.type}/${list2.id}`,
       mainList2: () => (
         <div>
           {`${list2.company} ${list2.name} ${list2.price}`}
         </div>
       ),
       sidebarList2: () => (
         <div>
           <h3>item List 2 selected</h3>
            {list2.company}
         </div>
       )
     }));

    return (
       <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
         <div style={{ width: '20%' }}>

           {dataList1.map(route => (
             <div>
               <Route
                 key={route.path}
                 path={`/search-page/${route.path}`}
                 exact={route.exact}
                 component={route.sidebarList1}
               />
             </div>
           ))}

           {dataList2.map(route => (
             <div>
               <Route
                 key={route.path}
                 path={`/search-page/${route.path}`}
                 exact={route.exact}
                 component={route.sidebarList2}
              />
             </div>
           ))}
         </div>
         <div>
           // Switch the lists when button is pressed
           {this.state.showListButtonPressed ? (
             <div>
               <ul>
                 {dataList1.map(route => (
                   <li key={route.path}>
                     <Link to={`/search-page/${route.path}`}>
                       {route.mainList1()}
                     </Link>
                   </li>
                 ))}
               </ul>
                <button onClick={this.showTheOtherList}> 
                  Switch Lists
                </button>
             </div>
           ) : (
             <div>
               <ul>
                 {dataList2.map(route => (
                   <li key={route.path}>
                     <Link to={`/search-page/${route.path}`}>
                       {route.mainList2()}
                     </Link>
                   </li>
                 ))}
               </ul>

               <button onClick={this.showTheOtherList}> 
                 switch Lists 
               </button>
             </div>
           )}
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

here are some screenshots to have a better idea :

[image: What I already done and coded]
[image: This is what I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difficult part is that since you're using 2 path params, it doesn't function exactly the same as the example they use. Let's say you have "n" list1 options, and "m" list2 options. That means you would n x m total routes. For it to work like this, you would need to create a list2 route combined with every list1 option. Then the `path` key for list2 would look something like `${this.props.match.params.type}/${list1.id}/${list2.id}`. I think this could also be achieved this by making the path for list2 `${this.props.match.url}/${list2.id}`, but it would require that the list1 is always selected first.

It's a pretty tricky case, but I hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use different approaches to solve this:

1. Get another inspiration from official React Router v4 [recursive paths](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths).

Using this pattern you can create deeply nested lists, more than 2 levels deep.

2. Check if there are already 1 item selected at first level in your sidebar and render another `<SidebarRoute />` for that case, passing second level seleted item as a prop.

I would suggest you (3rd option) to hold selected items in state, and render accordingly in sidebar. This option will work out just fine, if you are not obligated to send links by e-mail or something, just want to render. Then you can save UI state in the store of your choice (redux, flux, you name it).

Basic example for 2nd approach (idlvl2 is what you are trying to show in sidebar): https://codesandbox.io/s/o53pq1wvz

Comment: I'm actually trying to adapt the official React Router v4 https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths 
to my problem. Do you have any idea how to implement that?

Comment: Before you are going to implement something, explain what you are trying to achieve UI-wise. Your question is answered with different approaches and examples. I guess you're trying to show only 2 levels, probably arrival - departure airports, but this levels not necessarily meant to be nested anyway. Just a guess.

Comment: I think I gave a lot of details in my question, and I explained with code and even pictures explaining what my goal is. Trey’s answer is the one that showed me the right direction and you can only select one answer. And by the way the example that you posted is from the official documentation so it doesn’t give anything new

Comment: Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

This might just be a typo, but in your render component, you have forgotten to add Router to your outermost div. Route components have to be defined inside a Router component.

Comment: I haven’t forgotten to add a router. The router is in the parent component (that I didn’t post in the question ). In react-router-v4 routes are defined at the component level.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can use search params.

However if you have no chance to change the logic of path receiver component, you need [recursive paths](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths) Routes as suggested.

So about the search params. So instead of adding `localhost:3000/search-page/Lists/itemList1selected/itemList2selected`, add `localhost:3000/search-page/Lists?item1=itemList1selected&item2=itemList2selected`.

You can extract values by [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), beware it does not supported by IE.

There are 3 pros to this approach. First it will always render List, which will handle the logic, no need of nested Routes. Second you can add several items, not just two. Third url will handle all the logic, you can share the link and expect the same result.